# How can i dispaly Spicial Character from Sqlc to C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to display one String which is comes from SQLC. String is Like **"Hello This demo & i want that"** this string is strore in database.
Out put side i only display **"Hello This demo &"** I want to display full string **"Hello This demo & i want that"** in C#

Comment: What's the size of the field in the database?

Comment: You have to rephrase question. Is this winform app? Are you assigning text to the control property?

Comment: Yes, for instance, what is Sqlc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem occurs because the char &
You need to encode your data before you store it in db, and decode it after you getting data from db.

**Example**

```
string value = "Hello This demo & i want that";

    // 1. Encode your html before you store it in your db
    value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
    //Now you can store it in your db

    //Decode your values from the db before you present it on page.
    value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
```

I also suggesting to prevent sql injection before you store data in db.

for example see this function

```
    protected string Injection(string str)
{
    //Checks for remarks, new commands and string inputs.
    if (str.Contains("--"))
        str.Remove(str.IndexOf('-'), 1);
    else if (str.Contains(";"))
        str.Remove(str.IndexOf(';'),1);

    return str.Replace("'","''");

}
```

you can add more protection.

i hope it will help you